Open File Dialogue does not close after selection (Python 3.13)
I  m running 12.7 on an iMac and using Python 3.13.
I have a 3D graph plotting script that at the moment I open using Python Launcher3. It work fine and quickly, but the window for choosing and opening  the needed .xlsx* data file doesn't close after a file is selected, and it cannot be closed. When the file is selected by hitting the 'open' button a small empty window  'tk' opens. The shell and editor windows also open (I don't need either),
*spreadsheet is originally .osd and saved as 'xlsx which was just easier to code
An image of the graph appears with data points plotted which I  can rotate, save, etc.  If I save the image, all windows remain open. If I close the image, the tk window and the file select window also close, and in the editor window show Saving session... ...[Process competed]. If I close the  tk window before closing graph image Python crashes. The shell and editor must be manually closed.
Here is the code from the script for choosing a file:
import  tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path=filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(file_path)

df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
print(df.head)
print(df.columns)

I have tried adding the following  before and after several lines, but it does not help.
root.destroy()

but no change
I could just live with it, but I am hoping it is one or two lines of code to correct this.
